# I want to make VB.NET effects

Tags: vb.net, tooltip, effects

I want to write a program that creates cool effects in VB.NET.

Few example of what the program should do:

- How to make an intro to my program? I know how to make a splash form but can I put an animated logo?
- I want to put effects to buttons, such as the effects in the (HTML-CSS) websites, and also in the professional programs.
- Finally , Can I make notification-icon (Tool-Tip), like Avast 2015 ? > https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR2yZ.jpg

Comment: state one wuestion first

Comment: well , this is a one question under a title (VB.NET Effect) if u can answer any one of them no proplem

Comment: Programming 101 - "Using the correct tool": [Introduction to WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970268%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to modify a splash screen for an animated logo. Try using a picture box with a logo picture in a .gif format. However I've never tried that before.(Worth a shot tho)

For button effects there are many ways to do it. You can add sounds, add pictures/icons,ect.

I've never done much with tool tips before, however they can be done. To make them look like the image you provided, I don't think would be easy.

Comment: .gif are special pictures which animate but you have to make an animation. Try using this site: http://gifmaker.me/